# OAuth авторизация android

Tags: java, android, oauth

Встала задача, написать клиент серверное приложение android. Сразу говорю: android знаю я на уровне новичка, сильно тяжелыми камнями прошу не кидать. 
Сама проблема с `oauth` авторизацией, как её реализовать ? У меня получилась примерно такая схема:

1. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку авторизации в первом `activity`
2. Во втором окне открывается страница браузера, из которой извлекается
   токен.
3. Дальше, по идее, токен должен отправиться в первое `activity`, где
   потом с ним он продолжит работу. НО тут и встает проблема, как
   передать из класса `WebViewClient` данные в первое `activity` ?

Пробовал вот так, но не работает.`

```
public class VkWebView extends WebViewClient {

    Activity activity = new clientLogin();

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html")) {
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            mainActivity.putExtra("token", token);
            activity.startActivity(mainActivity);
        }else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Даже не знаю куда кидаться, так как мне кажется, что подход в корне не правильный. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!)

Comment: я думаю, вам стоит посмотреть начальный курс уроков по Android, потому что вы вообще не представляете себе, что такое `Activity`, `Context`, и как с ними работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала изучите [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk).

> Для авторизации есть несколько методов:
>
> > `VKSdk.login(Activity runningActivity, String... scope);`
> >
> > `VKSdk.login(Fragment runningFragment, String... scope);`

А также подробно описано как это обработать и что делать дальше.